# Turning a ReactJS project into a react-native app

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-native, express

I made a React.JS application with an Express.JS local backend.

What is the easiest way to turn it into an executable app?

[image: File directory]

It seems that using electron would need to recreate the whole project with different folders.

What are the other possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of turning a web application into an app fast is by creating a [**PWA**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_app).

It becomes a mobile app that does not require you to:

1. Create a Google play account.
2. Create a App Store Connect account
3. Compile and deploy your app to any store whatsoever

Since you don't need a store, you will not need some things like being restricted into their legal terms, and have your own page on those stores.

Instead, the user would access your PWA app in the same URL as your web application, just would need some code to your web app to identify if the user is accessing by using a Mobile device or a PC (Or something else).

Some PWA app examples are:

[Twitter lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twitter.android.lite)

Starbucks

Tinder

Spotify

Ifood

Here are some tutorials on how to do this:

[Convert Your Website Into A PWA App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_samZ3VQOU)

[Integrating a ReactJS Progressive Web App (PWA) with a React Native mobile app to enable bidirectional communication](https://hashithkarunarathne.medium.com/reactjs-pwa-react-native-app-integration-with-both-way-communication-368f0632df0d)

[How to create Progressive Web Apps (PWA) with React Native](https://www.techaheadcorp.com/blog/progressive-web-apps-with-react-native/)